recursively change the value of field in mongodb document
I need to change a value of a field in a mongoDB document recursively.
More or less, this is just a find and replace for a value of a field if the field name and the (old) value matches.
Example Document:
{
  "topLevel": {
    "level1": [
      {
        "itemKey": "N-99999",
        "level2": [
          {
            "itemKey": "N-99999",
            "level3": [
              {
                "itemKey": "N-99999"
              },
              {
                "itemKey": "a-4157-637"
              },
              {
                "itemKey": "t-3213-569"
              },
              {
                "itemKey": "s-3984-763"
              },
              {
                "itemKey": "n-5996-963"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

What I tried, but doesn't work:
func replaceItemKey(ctx context.Context, coll *mongo.Collection, old, new string) (*mongo.UpdateResult, error) {
    filter := bson.D{
        {Key: "toplevel.level1.itemKey", Value: old},
        {Key: "toplevel.level1.level2.itemKey", Value: old},
        {Key: "toplevel.level1.level2.level3.itemKey", Value: old},
    }
 
    update := bson.D{
        {Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{{Key: "toplevel.$[l1]level1.itemKey", Value: new}}},
        {Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{{Key: "toplevel.level1.$[].level2.$[l2].itemKey", Value: new}}},
        {Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{{Key: "toplevel.level1.$[].level2.$[].level3.$[l3].itemKey", Value: new}}},
    }
    
    opts := options.Update().SetArrayFilters(
        options.ArrayFilters{
            Filters: []interface{}{
                bson.D{{Key: "l1.itemKey", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$eq", Value: old}}}},
                bson.D{{Key: "l2.itemKey", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$eq", Value: old}}}},
                bson.D{{Key: "l3.itemKey", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$eq", Value: old}}}},
            },
        },
    )
    
    return coll.UpdateMany(ctx, filter, update, opts)
}




I know this is not recursively at all. It just tries to change the value in 3 levels.
Recursively would be better.
I'd prefer to change the value in one statement.
Doing it in a statement per level works fine. But I'm not aware on the performance impact if I have to change thousends of documents.
Thanks a lot.
